# How to get primitive values only from str.split() in an Ember js project

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I simply want "just" the primitive values from a str.split() from within my Ember.js project, instead of getting the primitive split values, I get a waterfall of ember prototypes!

**Example**

```
for(var num in "1,2,3,4".split(",")){
  console.log(num);
}
```

**Result (without Ember):**

```
0
1  
2 
3
```

**Result (with Ember)**

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
nextObject 
firstObject 
lastObject 
contains 
getEach 
setEach 
mapBy 
mapProperty 
reject 
filterBy 
filterProperty 
rejectBy 
rejectProperty 
find 
findBy 
findProperty 
everyBy 
everyProperty 
any 
anyBy 
someProperty 
invoke 
toArray 
compact 
without 
uniq 
[] 
addEnumerableObserver 
removeEnumerableObserver 
hasEnumerableObservers 
enumerableContentWillChange 
enumerableContentDidChange
```

Here's my jsbin.. http://jsbin.com/rodul/1/edit?html,js,console

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Simply dont use `for` -`in`, it is one of the bad parts of javascript (and now people know which book I am refering too :-) You cant rely of the result, as you experience.

Comment: that is kind of interesting behaviour, no help but thanks for raising the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you iterate over every property within the returned array of `split()` and Ember adds a lot to the `Array.prototype` scope so that you're able to get `firstObject` or `lastObject` easily (for example) - see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html for more information.

To make a long story short: if you use `forEach` or a simple `for` loop, you will see the expected behaviour. See your updated jsbin here http://jsbin.com/dixihiqi/1/

In general, I would use a `for in` for objects rather than arrays... (but that's just me)